# What returntype should I use when returning a Java object?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-7

What returntype should I use when returning a Java object created with `createObject("java", "<someclass>")` from a function?

Is "Any" the only solution?

Comment: What have you tried? I would start by dumping the object to look at its 'type' and try using that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, for java objects use `type="any"`.  Aside from "any", [cffunction](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/7/htmldocs/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=ColdFusion_Documentation&file=00000263.htm#wp2852457) only supports basic types (string, numeric, struct, query, etcetera...). Everything else is assumed to be a component name. So using a java class name, such as `java.lang.String`, would cause an error because CF looks for a component with that path and obviously does not find it.